# Sum the squares of the even numbers from a list in Haskell

Tags: list, dictionary, haskell, filter

I want to sum ​​the squares of the even numbers from a list. I try this but show an error.

```
sumaDeCuadrados :: [Int] -> Int
sumaDeCuadrados (x:xs) = sumaListAux (map f l) 0 
    where l = filter even (x:xs) 
          f = x * x
sumaDeCuadrados _ = 0
```

and sumaListAux is a function defined as ..

```
sumaListAux :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
sumaListAux [] r = r
sumaListAux (x:xs) r = x + sumaListAux xs r
```

Comment: Never state "there is an error" in a question without posting the details. It is as informative as an answer stating only "there is a fix".

Comment: replace `f = x * x` with `f x = x * x` and it will work. The first equation defines a number, the second equation defines a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem is, `map` expects the first argument to be a function, which accepts an integer and returning an integer, but you are passing it an integer. That is why you are getting an error message like this

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int -> Int' with actual type `Int'
In the first argument of `map', namely `f'
In the first argument of `sumaListAux', namely `(map f l)'
In the expression: sumaListAux (map f l) 0
```

So, you need to define `f` as a separate function, so that `map` can apply that function to `l`. I would recommend naming the function with something appropriate, like `squarer`

```
squarer :: Int -> Int
squarer x = x * x

sumaDeCuadrados xs = sumaListAux (map squarer (filter even xs)) 0
```

And then you can call it like this

```
main = print $ sumaDeCuadrados [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
-- 20
```

Answer (score 6):

> sum ​​the squares of the even numbers from a list.

Haskell is a declarative language in some ways, so you can just declare what these things mean.

```
-- declare a list
> let list = [1..10]

-- declare what the even elements of a lsit are
> let evens xs = filter even xs

-- declare what the squares of a list are
> let squares xs = map (^2) xs
```

and the sum is already there, `sum`. So now your sentence:

```
 sum ​​the squares of the even numbers
```

can be transposed to:

```
> sum . squares . evens $ list
220
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answers above, it's possible to do this entirely using higher order functions.

```
sumEvenSquares :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sumEvenSquares xs = sum(map(^2)(filter even xs))
```

In this case, you're able to filter the list using the even predicate, and map the function (^2) onto it. From this returned list, you're then able to sum it.